How to setup barbecue plugin for Neovim?
I try to setup the pluging utilyre/barbecue The part that I could not setup is where we can use the mouse on the winbar to navigate through the modules, code, ..
This is a part of the original code in the README file:
Navigate to entry
-- navigate to the second entry
require("barbecue.ui").navigate(2)

-- navigate to the last entry
require("barbecue.ui").navigate(-1)

-- just like before but on the given window
require("barbecue.ui").navigate(index, winnr)

I dont know how to setup this part and also the index number.  If I want to navigate to entry 1, 4 7, .. how do I integrate that part in my setup ?

it depends on which plugin manager you're using! so please confirm which neovim plugin manager you're using

I am using lazy.nvim.  When declaring a pluging I use this syntax: Return { "utilyre/barbecue.nvim",  ... other specs here }.

Just needed to activate the mouse in Neovim.  I added in init.lua:
vim.cmd [[set mouse=a]]

Now it is working without any extra setup.
